# Criar uma variável superglobal php

Tags: php

Estou criando um site, e todas minhas funções que uso nele estão em um arquivo chamado `Funct.php`.

Por isso quando tenho que utilizar alguma função, tenho que chamar esses arquivos usando o `request Funct.php` e, dependendo da pasta que estou, tenho que acrescentar "../".

Observei o *framework Laravel* e ele tem um arquivo `.ENV` onde tem as variáveis de conexão com o banco de dados, sendo assim essas variáveis são consideradas **"superglobal"** tal como o `post` ou `get`.

Por essa razão queria saber como faço para criar uma variável **superglobal** para que eu posa chamar em qualquer lugar sem a nessesidade de usar o `Request`

Comment: Você quer dizer `require`? O Laravel usa isto: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso você tem que ter um arquivo que vai ser chamado em todas as paginas, ou com require ou com include, Exemplo eu trabalho muito com variaveis globais, no meu caso eu uso constante, e uso da seguinte forma

1. Tenho um arquivo chamado config.inc.php
2. Este arquivo esta presente em todas as paginas do meu site

o codigo é mais ou menos assim:

```html
// Definição de Dados do Site
define('NOMESITE', 'PortalCod');
define('RAIZ'    , 'http://localhost');
define('LOGO'    , '<h1><font style="color: #0099cc " >Por</font>tal<font style="color: #0099cc " >Cod</font></h1>');
```

Então eu tenho uma regra basica na hora de desenvolver o site que é a seguinte, o arquivo de configuração tem q estar presente em todas as paginas

```
include './inc/config.inc.php';
```

Normalmente essa é a primeira linha de todos os meus arquivos.

1. Criar um arquivo global (arquivo comum com os dados q você quer usar no site inteiro)
2. Usar o include para incluir este arquivo em todas as paginas
3. Criar a constante `define('NOMESITE', 'PortalCod');`

E quando você quiser usar você vai chama-las assim: `<?php echo RAIZ; ?>`